# SQL query joining on existing date records and max date for missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have an items table with dates and values. As soon as the value gets to 1, there are no more records for that Itemid.

```
Item Table
Itemid  ItemDate      Value
1       2020-04-30    0.5
1       2020-05-31    0.75
1       2020-06-30    1.0
2       2020-05-31    0.6
2       2020-06-30    1.0
```

I want to join this with a simple date table

```
dateId  EOMDate 
1       2020-04-30
2       2020-05-31
3       2020-06-30
4       2020-07-31
5       2020-08-31
```

The result should produce one record for each date in the date table and for each item where the date is >= the Item date. Where there is an exact date match with the Item table, it will use that record from the item table. Where there is no matching record in the item table, then it uses the record with the Max(ItemDate) value, that exists in the item table.

So it should produce this:

```
Result  EOMDate     ItemDate    Value
1       2020-04-30  2020-04-30  0.5
1       2020-05-31  2020-05-31  0.75
1       2020-06-30  2020-06-30  1.0
1       2020-07-31  2020-06-30  1.0
1       2020-08-31  2020-06-30  1.0
2       2020-05-31  2020-05-31  0.6
2       2020-06-30  2020-06-30  1.0
2       2020-07-31  2020-06-30  1.0
2       2020-08-31  2020-06-30  1.0
```

The item table has several hundred millions of rows, and the date table has 120 records (each month end for 10 years), so I need a good performing solution. This has completely stumped me for some reason!

EDIT
my initial and non-working solution uses an outer apply

```
select p.ItemId, p.ItemDate, d.EOMDate, p.Value
from (select ItemId, ItemDate, Value from Items) p
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT EOMDate from dates
) d
order by p.ItemDate,d.EOMDate
```

However it returns a table that has one record for each combination of Item date and EOM date. So in the above example, 20 records for ItemId 1 and 16 records for ItemId2

Here is to sql to create the above example tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #Items (ItemId int, ItemDate date, [Value] float)
Insert into #Items (ItemId,ItemDate,[Value]) 
Values (1,'2020-04-30',0.5),(1,'2020-05-31',0.75),(1,'2020-06-30',1),(2,'2020-05-31',0.6),(2,'2020-06-30',1)
Create Table #dates (dateId int, EOMDate date) 
Insert into #dates (dateId,EOMDate) Values (1,'2020-04-30'),(2,'2020-05-31'),(3,'2020-06-30'),(4,'2020-07-31'),(5,'2020-08-31')
```

Comment: @DaleK I only have half an attempt, but I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `apply`:

```
select i.*, d.*
from (select item_id, max(date) as max_date
      from items
      group by item_id
     ) i outer apply
     (select top (1) d.*
      from dates d
      where d.date >= max_date
      order by d.date asc
     ) d
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, but this only returns one record for the max date

Comment: @Jason . . . I don't think I understand the question then.  I thought you wanted the rows in the first table with the first "after" date in the second.

Comment: Hi @Gordon, sorry will try to explain. In the example for Item 1 there are three values. The result should return one record for each record in the date table like a normal inner join. Additionally for the two rows where there is no date match, it should return the item row that has the max date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` and analytical function as follows:

```
Select * from
(Select a.item_id, d.eomdate, i.itemdate, i.value,
        Row_number() over (partition by a.item_id, d.eomdate order by i.itemdate) as rn
From
(Select distinct item_id from items) a
Cross join Dates d 
join items i on i.item_id = a.item_id and d.eomdate >= i.item_date) t
Where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Popeye but this also only returned one record

Comment: Ok. Updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: Hi @Popeye, thanks for the alternative, but alas that doesn't do it either. This is returning the same record from items table, joined with each date. Any other thoughts? It should be straightforward, but I keep hitting a wall and can't resolve it.